# Installing basemap: setup.py encounters an error

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I followed the rules [here](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html) to install basemap step by step. But error occured at last.

When I typed the command: python setup.py, an erorr appears as follows:

```
gddxz@ubuntu:~/Downloads/basemap-1.0.7$ python setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 92, in <module>
    if sys.argv[1] not in ['sdist','clean']:
IndexError: list index out of range
gddxz@ubuntu:~/Downloads/basemap-1.0.7$
```

If there is anyone encountering the similar problem? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this command requires at least one parameter. According to the instructions you should execute `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 1):

seems to have worked: 'python setup.py install'